# Description not "wrapping" in boxxy box

Tags: jquery, css

I have a boxxy box with CSS that I have some information in.  I have a string in it called "description", that is running outside of the box (it gets cut off, so it isn't running outside of the box, but only the first line is showing), instead of wrapping:

Diagram:

What it is:

```
[heyooo this is a] 
[                ]
```

What I want:

```
[heyooo this is a]
[sentence        ]
```

This is the html in my view:

```
<div id="boxxy-list">           
    <ul class="additional-artists">
    @foreach ($artists as $artist)
        <li>
        <div class="boxxy">
            <a href="/artists/{{$artist->id}}" class="anchor-hover">
            <img src="{{ $artist->image_path}}" alt="{{$artist->stage_name}}" height="200" width="200">
            <span class="details">
                <h2>{{$artist->stage_name}}</h2>
                <p class="desc">{{$artist->description}}</p> //this is the portion that is not wrapping like it should.
                <span class="pupdate">{{ $artist->city}}, {{ $artist->state}}</span>
                <span class="viewlink">Play My City</span>
            </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </li>

    @endforeach

    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxxy { display: block; margin: 0 auto; background:#fff; margin-bottom: 22px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); width: 200px; padding:7px 7px;
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear 0s; -webkit-
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear 0s; -moz-
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.anchor-hover {display: block; position: relative;}
.anchor-hover img { position: relative; }

.anchor-hover .details { opacity: 0; position:absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; width: 200px; height:200px; margin: 0; padding-top: 0px; padding-left:0px; font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 0.1em; color:#8c8a7d; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85); overflow: hidden; transition: opacity 0.25s linear 0s; -webkit-
transition: opacity 0.25s linear 0s; -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s linear 0s; -o-transition: opacity 0.25s linear 0s;
}

.anchor-hover .details h2 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; color: #3c527d; margin-bottom: 8px; text-decoration:none;
}

.anchor-hover .details p.desc { font-family:'proxima-nova';
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#8c8a7d;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.anchor-hover .details span.pubdate { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left:10px; font-weight: 500; font-family: 'proxima-nova', Tahoma, sans-serif; }
.anchor-hover .details span.viewlink { position:absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-weight:bold; color: #3c527d; font-size: 1.3em;}

.anchor-hover:hover .details {opacity: 1;}
.boxxy:hover {box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 0 10px rgba(71, 123, 164, 0.7); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0, 0, 10px rgba(71, 123, 164, 0.7); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0, 0, 10px rgba(71, 123, 164, 0.7);}

#boxxy-list a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Do you see something I'm not?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle based on you code, please review: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/m9rxj/ I don't see the problem that you are describing.  You must have some other styles that are over-riding the ones that you posted.  Why don't you post a link to the page of interest?

Comment: Please don't post your PHP. Post the outputted HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox or Chrome, open your website and right click, select "Inspect Element..." while hovering over or around your .boxxy and child elements. You should see some CSS styles. See if width or any other values have been crossed out. My top guess:

- .desc has some overriding div element from a different location that sets widths, or padding, or margins.

This is an important way to debug CSS, so if you have not already done it, I would strongly advise it. If you don't want to do that, please remove all CSS references except for this one and work out from there, line by line, in your CSS code, or, if you'd like more help, share all of your CSS code. Before you get through it all you'll probably see what's wrong though!

Example from Firefox:
[image: Boxxy Box Debugging]

Comment: This was the case; I had a "white-space:nowrap" style on an element that wrapped this.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your `line-height` for `.anchor-hover .details` in your CSS to `1em`.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbfd8/

Comment: @user1072337 You will need to provide more information. Edit your question with the output HTML and any other contributing factors. Better yet create a fiddle which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this in JSFiddle strangely, but it is still having the problem on my server.

Comment: @user1072337 Then the problem must be with another conflicting library or style. If the problem only exists on your server it makes it very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: You could always just add `!important` to this style to double check that it is the problem, then track down the style that's overwriting it later on?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding !important to this style doesn't fix the problem.  I've tried changing everything in firebug, and it's not working...very strange

Comment: Looks like absolute positioning _could_ be the culprit. Check and make sure it doesn't have position absolute. Then check that `white-space` property is set to default.

Comment: ok, when I change it from absolute to relative, all of the text is shown but it is not contained within the box (it is not wrapped).

Answer (score 0):

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

That should do the trick. Put this inside of your .boxxy class. This will wrap the words within the box so that they do not overflow out of the box and hide.

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `overflow: hidden;` is not applied to the element. If it is you can set `overflow: initial;`